Impersonate user using angular and .net core in abp framework (Version 6.0.2)
I using ABP framework version 6.0.2 (angular and .net core)
The requirement is logged in as a super admin.
I have a dropdown list with the user list and when the super admin selects the user and clicks the button, I need to impersonate as the selected user with all existing user permissions.
I tried the below api call but I am getting authorization issue.
public async Task<IActionResult> ImpersonateUser(String userId)
    {
        var currentUserId = User.GetUserId();

        var impersonatedUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

        var userPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(impersonatedUser);

        userPrincipal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("OriginalUserId", currentUserId));
        userPrincipal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("IsImpersonating", "true"));

        // sign out the current user
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, userPrincipal); 

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

Regards,
N.ShanthaKumar.
